# How to control view items in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have CI framework and user, group permission control applied in controller,

But how can i apply restriction in some buttons, links, etc in view?
Example, below is code for new, edit, delete buttons, if i want to disble\hide this buttons

```
<button type="button" class="btn blue" id="new_group_showbtn"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn purple" id="edit_group_showbtn"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn yellow" id="delete_group_btn"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>
```

I used control over controller as below

```
if($this->mylib->access('testcontrol'))
{
    \\code.....

} //Access control END
```

How can i put such control over views? I am not echoing views, but loading pure html as view,

Can be done with passing some variables? How?

Thanks,

Comment: where ever access is required, check the condition, if true then show to user...

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju, How can i check condition in views?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

Store the user type in session on ligin(like admin, subadmin,...)

Suppose i want to show a button by name `create sub admin` only to user, i would do like this,

```
<?php if($this->session->userdata("user_type") == "admin") { ?>
     <button>Add Sub Admin</button>
<?php } ?>
```

something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Since session variables are global variables you can use them across any pages( even in views).

So while you allowing user to login,
set one session variable to appropriate value according to user type.

may be something like this

```
$this->session->set_userdata('privilege', 'user');
$this->session->set_userdata('privilege', 'manager');
```

then in the view,
 you can check them like,

```
 <html>
  <body>

  <div>
  <?php if($this->session->userdata("privilege") == "manager") { ?>
    <button type="button" class="btn yellow" id="delete_group_btn"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>
  <?php } ?>
  </div>

 .
 .
 .
</body>
<html>
```

above code only display the delete button to the user type manager.
like that you can check the condition.